# "Away'' Adjective Or Adverb?

Tags: grammar, differences, adjectives, adverbs

I give an example below.

"They've got the kind of weapons that can zap the enemy from thousands of miles away."

```
How to determine here that "away" is adjective or adverb?
```

Comment: You've asked this question on other forums too. In trad grammar it's an adverb -- in modern grammar a preposition.

Comment: It's a preposition.